# When is it useful to use "grep -- SOMEPATTERN"?

Tags: command-line, syntax

Under Linux/AIX where ever, when is it useful to use `--`, as in this command:

```
grep -- SOMEPATTERN
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When "SOMEPATTERN" starts or *may* start (for instance if it's a variable like `"$PATTERN"` which you don't have full control on) with a `-` (dash) character.

Also with GNU grep (unless `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is on), it's useful if other arguments (file names) may start with `-`.

Alternatively, you can do

```
grep -e -SOMEPATTERN- -- file1 file2 -xxx-
```

`--` marks the end of options. It's useful everywhere where non-option arguments may start with a `dash`, and it doesn't harm, so it's a good habit to use it.

Answer (score 8):

When the pattern starts with a dash, otherwise grep will think it is an option. Say, you are looking for "-a" in a text:

```
grep -a file.txt
```

grep will then try to find the pattern "file.txt" in the standard input, using the option `-a`. Therefore, you need to do

```
grep -- -a file.txt
```

Comment: This does not only hold for `grep`.